# 'Exception ignored in:' cython extension classes and their `cdef` methods

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I have some cython classes, and in their `cdef` methods, I have `assert` statements. However, instead of getting an `AssertionError` that I can catch, for example, I get `Exception ignored in:` and I cannot catch it (`pytest` reports this as warnings as well)
Moreover, other errors happening (other than the `assert` one) are not raised and ignored.

As a simple example, let's say I have a Node class called `Node.pyx`

```
cdef class Node:
    def __init__(self, ident):
        self.identifier = ident
        self.children = set()
        self.parents = set()

    cdef void add_child(self, Node child):
        self.children.add(child.identifier)
        child.parents.add(self.identifier)

    cdef void add_parent(self, Node parent):
        self.parent.add(parent.identifier)
        parent.children.add(self.identifier)

    cdef void remove_child(self, Node child):
        assert child.identifier in self.children

        self.children.remove(child.identifier)
        child.parents.remove(self.identifier)

    cdef void remove_parent(self, Node parent):
        assert parent.identifier in self.parents

        self.parents.remove(parent.identifier)
        parent.children.remove(self.identifier)
```

and its corrisponding `Node.pxd` file

```
cdef class Node:
    cdef int identifier
    cdef set children
    cdef set parents

    cdef void add_child(self, Node child)
    cdef void add_parent(self, Node parent)
    cdef void remove_child(self, Node child)
    cdef void remove_parent(self, Node parent)
```

As this is all `cdef`, it can only be used by another `pyx` script or function. So let's have another script testing the nodes, `node_test.pyx`

```
from Node cimport Node

def test_error_raising():
        cdef Node node1 = Node(1)
        cdef Node node2 = Node(2)

        node1.remove_parent(node2)
```

Now if I compile all of this with `cythonize -i *pyx` or a simpel setup script, all compiles well. However, running this `test_node.py`

```
from node_test import test_error_raising

try:
    test_error_raising()
except AssertionError:
    print("You have assertion error!")
```

I get

```
AssertionError
Exception ignored in: 'Node.Node.remove_parent'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_node.py", line 5, in <module>
    test_error_raising()
AssertionError:
```

System and versions:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Cython version 0.29.21

Python 3.8.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem was fairly easy to solve. One should remove the `void` from the `cdef` function in order for it to return a proper error message, instead of the error being ignored.
Reason is that when the function is defined that it's going to have `void` return, the error message will be created, reported, destroyed and the function will return from the exception point and the return statement will never be executed.

So by just removing the `void` from the `remove_child` and `remove_parent` functions in both `.pyx` and `.pxd` will make it behave as expected and the error message can be cought normally.

More information [here](https://notes-on-cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/misc.html)

Comment: I think doing `cdef void func() except *` would work too. It tells Cython that the function can raise an error, and to always check the Python error state after calling the function.

Comment: True! I realized this after. I just decided to post the question and answer it in case someone falls in the same trap as myself and didn't read the cython documentation very thoroughly and gets confused later.

Answer (score 3):

See:

https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#error-return-values

In addition to the above, the useful:

```
cdef <some_type> some_func() except? -1:

cdef <some_type> some_func() except *:

cdef <some_type> some_func() except +:
```

forms are described.